# Contact forms ajax PHP call prints echo on screen instead of returning success

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I'm trying to set up a small personal page based on [kite](http://demos.jeweltheme.com/kite). It comes along with a sleak contact form.

However, I was not able to get this contact form to work. After many hours, I managed to get it to send emails, but now it doesn't return a proper 'success' status, so the contact form gets updated. Instead, the echo 'success' in the called php gets printed on screen. The eMail, however, is being sent.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
    <form id="contact-form" action="email.php" method="post" class="clearfix">
      <div class="contact-box-hide">
        //in here is the contact-box form 
      </div><!-- /.contact-box-hide -->

    <div id="contact-message" class="contact-message"></div>
    //This is the div, in which the success message should be posted

   </form><!-- /#contact-form -->
```

**AJAX Call**

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "email.php", //if I use this line, the mail is not being sent, but the email.php script hands over a proper success message to the ajax call
            url: $(form).attr('action'), //if I use this line, the mail will be sent, but the email.php script prints its echo on a blank page
            data: data_string,

            //success
            success: function(data) {

                $('.contact-box-hide').slideUp();
                $('.contact-message').html('<i class="fa fa-check contact-success"></i><div>Super, die Nachricht ist raus.</div>').fadeIn();
            },
            error: function(data) {

                $('.btn-contact-container').hide();
                $('.contact-message').html('<i class="fa fa-exclamation contact-error"></i><div>Mist. Da ist was schief gegangen. Versuchs später nochmal.</div>').fadeIn();
            }

        }) //end ajax call
```

**email.php**

```
<?php
if($_REQUEST['first_name'] == '' || $_REQUEST['contact_email'] == '' ||  $_REQUEST['message'] == ''):
  return "error";
endif;
if (filter_var($_REQUEST['contact_email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)):
  $subject = 'Mail von der Hochzeitsseite: ' . $_REQUEST['contact_subject']; // Subject of your email

  // Receiver email address
  $to = 'my@mailadress.de';


  // prepare header
  $header = 'From: '. $_REQUEST['first_name'] . " " . $_REQUEST['last_name'] . ' <'. $_REQUEST['contact_email'] .'>'. "\r\n";
  $header .= 'Reply-To:  '. $_REQUEST['first_name'] . " " . $_REQUEST['last_name'] . ' <'. $_REQUEST['contact_email'] .'>'. "\r\n";
  // $header .= 'Cc:  ' . 'example@domain.com' . "\r\n";
  // $header .= 'Bcc:  ' . 'example@domain.com' . "\r\n";
  $header .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


  $message = $_REQUEST['message'] . "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
  $message .= 'Name: ' . $_REQUEST['first_name'] . " " . $_REQUEST['last_name'] . "\n";
  $message .= 'Email: ' . $_REQUEST['contact_email'] . "\n";


  // Send contact information
  $mail = mail( $to, $subject , $message, $header );

  echo "success";
  else:
    return "error";
  endif; 

?>
```

Comment: You have it right there: `echo "success";`

Comment: You should learn to use Chrome's developer console Network Tab, to debug your script. Also because you do a `return "error"` it won't get echoed, so the ajax script won't pick up errors. You should do `echo "error"` instead.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to find the mistake. I am not sure what you are trying to point out though. I know that I have an `echo "success";` line there. However, this line is only being printed on a blank screen. It's intended to be given back to the ajax call, though.

Comment: @adrian7: I am willing to learn. Any particularly good how-to that you can recommmend? Also changing the return into an echo did not help :-/

Comment: Gets printed to the screen? Like your window is redirecting to email.php instead of staying put?

Answer (score 1):

Your form is getting submitted directly to `email.php`, it is not going through ajax.  That's what the `action` attribute is all about:

`<form id="contact-form" action="email.php"`

To use ajax instead, you need to remove the `action` attribute from the form and add a click handler to your submit button/link.  For example:

`<button onclick="doAjaxCall()">Submit Email</button>`

The ajax call itself, would look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "email.php",
      data: {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            address: $('#address').val(),
            ...
      },
...
```

Comment: Thanks raduation. That helped!